# Nav Dropdown Dissapears Sometimes

Tags: php, html, css

Hi there i was wondering if anyone could help me ?

I have an issue with CSS navigation dropdown that i have previous implemented in to designs but for this design the dropdown menu appears and are sometimes able to hover over the links but then sometimes it takes 5+ tries before you are able to hover over the links again abit hit and miss.

I have provided a link to the menu and also my code below its possible ive missed something so simple but any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Link: [Design / Menu](http://www.cl-labs.ml/)

Code: [CSS Code](http://www.cl-labs.ml/css_code.css)

Im unsure how to input the css code in to my post so i have linked above.

thanks in advance

Chris.

Comment: `#nav ul {margin-top: 0}` will fix your problem. If you really want a small space between the button and first link, you'll have to use `padding-top` in your `<ul>` for it. Or you can place an extra `<li>` at the top, containing a spacer.

Comment: You should post your code here, not link it. If that link becomes 404 it helps nobody in the future.

Comment: thank you  @AndreiGheorghiu that helped alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the space between the opener and the menu.
You can easily solve this removing the space (that is a `margin`) like this:

```
#nav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Or, if you want to mantain the space, replacing the `margin` with `padding`, like this:

```
#nav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: .6em;
}
```

The `padding` will allow the menu to stay open.
Hope it helps. Good luck.